# Which approach is best in loading URL in selenium web driver?

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to load the URL: using selenium web driver.Currently i have two approaches to make it

1. Using .get(url) method of WebDriver.

   ```
   driver.get(URL).
   ```
2. Using JavascriptExecutor

   ```
   ((JavascriptExecutor) pRobot.getDriver()).executeScript("window.location='URL'");
   ```

Which of the above approaches takes more time to load the URL??

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.get(URL)
```

1. This is the best method to launch url when compared to JavascriptExecutor.
2. .get(url) method will wait for url to load on your browser but not JavascriptExecutor.

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about which is fast, the answer is javascript for the obvious reason mentioned by SaiPawan.

Which one you should use, it depends on your use case.

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
last_time = time.time()
browser.get("https://google.com")
print "driver.get() time = %s" % str(time.time() - last_time)
last_time = time.time()
browser.execute_script("window.location='https://www.google.com'")
print "navigation through javascript time = %s" % str(time.time() - last_time)
```

**Execution output**

```
driver.get() time = 0.712184906006
navigation through javascript time = 0.116823911667
```